# How to load C# dll from python 2.7

Tags: c#, python-2.7, dll

I have c# project, so I wanted to call that dll by python 2.7.
I followed [Call the C# Methods from Python example][1] and I got the below error.

```
DynamicCalc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 20, in <module>
    print calc.add(a, b)
AttributeError: 'DynamicCalc' object has no attribute 'add'

  [1]: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/dynamic-language-integration-in-a-c-world/
```

Comment: The link explains how to call a C# method from a python code **running in IronPython** (https://ironpython.net/). It won't work with the "traditional" python 2.7 interpreter

Comment: There are alternatives though: http://pythonnet.github.io/ (but I haven't tried it)